# Msbuild and ClCompile options

Tags: c++, msbuild, cl, vcxproj

I compile C++ code with `msbuild` and I specify `cl` options inside `ClCompile` item. Something like...

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="something.cpp">
        <FloatingPointModel>Precise</FloatingPointModel>
        <WarningLevel>Level2</WarningLevel>
    </ClCompile>
</ItemGroup>

<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.default.props" />
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Targets" />
```

The above is just an example.  Now I want to print all options used for `cl` invocation.  The question is:  How do I do that?  My first attempt was to use something like the following:

```
<Target Name="WriteToFile" AfterTargets="ClCompile" >
    <WriteLinesToFile File="$(OutDir)\log.txt" Lines="@(ClCompile)" Overwrite="true" />
</Target>
```

Sadly, this logs only filename (`something.cpp`) and not the options.

Note that I'm aware that the compiler options are stored by `Tracker.exe` in `CL.command.*.tlog` file, but first, I don't want to rely on that as it's subject to change and second, I will most likely need to do some transformations later on. I also know that I could access individual options (like `%(ClCompile.FloatingPointModel)`), but I don't want handle each option separately either.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no trivial solutions to do that.
You could find a starting point [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461223/passing-items-to-msbuild-task)
and another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461175/how-to-get-all-the-metadata-keys-for-any-itemgroup-item)